# Change axis format of a chart in openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm working with an Excel line chart by using the library openpyxl. I would like to know how to format the axis, so I can modify it from text format to date format.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24936197) to include the code you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

`datetime.strptime()` might be of value in this instance to parse a string to a date format. openpyxl's `.number_format` might also be a solution based on which worksheet cell it is reading from.

---

References:

`strptime()`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

`number_format()`: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#using-number-formats